# How to iterate over multiple vectors to run multiple regressions in R

Tags: r, loops, regression, lapply

DATA BELOW

```
analysis<-tibble(off_race = c("hispanic", "hispanic", "white","white", "hispanic", "white", "hispanic", "white", "white", "white","hispanic"), any_black_uof = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), any_black_arrest = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), prop_white_scale = c(0.866619646027524, -1.14647499712298, 1.33793539994219, 0.593565300512359, -0.712819809606193, 0.3473585867755, -1.37025501425243, 1.16596624239715, 0.104521426674564, 0.104521426674564, -1.53728347122581),  prop_hisp_scale=c(-0.347382203637802, 1.54966785579018, 
    -0.833021026477168, -0.211470492567308, 1.48353691981021, 
    0.421968013870802, 2.63739845069911, -0.61002505397242, 0.66674880256898,0.66674880256898, 2.93190487813111))
```

I would like to run a series of regressions that iterate over these vectors

```
officer_race = c("black", "white", "hispanic")
primary_ind<-c("prop_white_scale","prop_hisp_scale","prop_black_scale")
outcome<-c("any_black_uof","any_white_uof","any_hisp_uof","any_black_arrest","any_white_arrest","any_hisp_arrest","any_black_stop","any_white_stop","any_hisp_stop")
```

Also of note, I would like to use the fixest package
where the regressions would look like this

```
feols(any_black_uof~ prop_white_scale,data=analysis[analysis$off_race =="black"])
feols(any_black_uof~ prop_white_scale,data=analysis[analysis$off_race =="white"])
feols(any_black_uof~ prop_white_scale,data=analysis[analysis$off_race=="hispanic"])
feols(any_black_uof~ prop_hisp_scale,data=analysis[analysis$off_race =="black"])
feols(any_black_uof~ prop_hisp_scale,data=analysis[analysis$off_race =="white"])
```

etc. iterating through all possible combinations and creating a list of lm objects.

Is this possible?

Comment: Could you provide sample data used in the models? Your data `race`, `primary_ind` and `outcome` are not in the models so are largely unhelpful. just provide `dput(analysis)`

Comment: Would it not be better to specify multiple terms in the formula `lm(any_black_uof ~ prop_white_scale + race, data = analysis)`?

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not provide sample data I am using `mtcars` dataset as an example dataset.

I am using `cyl` variable as equivalent to `race` in your example.

```
primary_ind <- c("mpg", "gear", "disp")
outcome <- c("hp", "wt")

result <- lapply(split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl), function(x) {
  sapply(primary_ind, function(y) {
    sapply(outcome, function(z) {
      lm(paste(y, z, sep = "~"), x)
    }, simplify = FALSE)
  }, simplify = FALSE)
})

result
```

First we `split` the data by `cyl` values so that we have (3) list for each unique value (4, 6 and 8). Then for each individual dataset loop over `primary_ind` and `outcome` values and apply `lm` for each combination.

`sapply` with `simplify = FALSE` helps to identify `primary_ind` and `outcome` value for each model as it is saved in the name of the list.

Comment: this actually doesn't work with the fixest package

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in multiple estimation tools: see the [dedicated vignette](https://lrberge.github.io/fixest/articles/multiple_estimations.html).
You also need to understand the formula expansion tools, presented [here](https://lrberge.github.io/fixest/articles/fixest_walkthrough.html#formula-macros).

It seems you want to iterate over subsets of the data for different explanatory and dependent variables.
Use `split` for the subsets and `sw` for the explanatory variables and `c()` for the dependent variables.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(fixest)

base = setNames(iris, c("y1", "y2", "x1", "x2", "species"))

lhs = c("y1", "y2")
rhs = c("x1", "x2")

mult_est = feols(.[lhs] ~  sw(.[, rhs]), base, split = ~ species)

etable(mult_est)
#>                         mult_est.1        mult_est.2        mult_est.3        mult_est.4
#> Sample (species)            setosa            setosa            setosa            setosa
#> Dependent Var.:                 y1                y1                y2                y2
#>                                                                                         
#> Constant         4.213*** (0.4156) 4.777*** (0.1239) 2.861*** (0.4564) 3.222*** (0.1349)
#> x1                0.5423. (0.2823)                     0.3879 (0.3100)                  
#> x2                                  0.9302. (0.4637)                     0.8372 (0.5049)
#> ________________ _________________ _________________ _________________ _________________
#> S.E. type                      IID               IID               IID               IID
#> Observations                    50                50                50                50
#> R2                         0.07138           0.07734           0.03158           0.05417
#> Adj. R2                    0.05204           0.05812           0.01140           0.03447
#> 
#>                          mult_est.5        mult_est.6         mult_est.7        mult_est.8
#> Sample (species)         versicolor        versicolor         versicolor        versicolor
#> Dependent Var.:                  y1                y1                 y2                y2
#>                                                                                           
#> Constant          2.408*** (0.4463) 4.045*** (0.4229)   1.175** (0.3421) 1.373*** (0.2296)
#> x1               0.8283*** (0.1041)                   0.3743*** (0.0798)                  
#> x2                                  1.426*** (0.3155)                    1.054*** (0.1713)
#> ________________ __________________ _________________ __________________ _________________
#> S.E. type                       IID               IID                IID               IID
#> Observations                     50                50                 50                50
#> R2                          0.56859           0.29862            0.31419           0.44089
#> Adj. R2                     0.55960           0.28401            0.29990           0.42925
#> 
#>                          mult_est.9       mult_est.10       mult_est.11        mult_est.12
#> Sample (species)          virginica         virginica         virginica          virginica
#> Dependent Var.:                  y1                y1                y2                 y2
#>                                                                                           
#> Constant            1.060* (0.4668) 5.269*** (0.6556) 1.673*** (0.4310)  1.695*** (0.2921)
#> x1               0.9957*** (0.0837)                   0.2343** (0.0773)                   
#> x2                                   0.6508* (0.3207)                   0.6314*** (0.1429)
#> ________________ __________________ _________________ _________________ __________________
#> S.E. type                       IID               IID               IID                IID
#> Observations                     50                50                50                 50
#> R2                          0.74688           0.07902           0.16084            0.28915
#> Adj. R2                     0.74161           0.05983           0.14335            0.27434
#> ---
#> Signif. codes: 0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```